# What are the unthinkable (acinteyya) dhamma?

Tags: reference-request, dhammas

I have heard there are 4 unthinkable (acinteyya) concepts in Buddhism. Not [Acintya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acintya).

The four imponderables are identified in the Acintita Sutta, Anguttara Nikaya 4.77, as follows:[5]

> - The Buddha-range of the Buddhas [i.e., the range of powers a Buddha
>     develops as a result of becoming a Buddha];
> - The jhana-range of one absorbed in jhana [i.e., the range of powers that one may obtain while absorbed in jhana];
> - The [precise working out of the] results of kamma;
> - Speculation about [the origin, etc., of] the cosmos is an imponderable that is not to be speculated about.

Why It says Unthinkable?

Comment: http://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php?title=Unthinkables

Comment: @inzenity Thankyou for the link. This link says "Anithya" as acinteyya dhamma. i think it is thinkable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is given in the sutta itself. Pondering on these brings *madness* and *frustration* for someone with an undeveloped mind.

> "These are the four unconjecturables that are not to be conjectured
>   about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured
>   about them."
>   http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.077.than.html#fnt-1